# How to tell which value belongs to the key during hashing

Tags: hash-tables, linked-lists

To prevent collisions in Hash table , [seperate chaining with linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) is used . Hash table works by hashing the key and storing the value in the bucket.

Assuming 4 keys hash to the same bucket , and the bucket has a linked list which has 4 nodes , how would we know which value belong to the key when we try to search for the value of the key .

For eg : These 4 key-value :**a:4**  , **b:3** , **c:2** , **d:1** ,  hash to bucket 23. At bucket 23 , there is a linked list of values : **4 , 3 , 2 , 1**  , how would we know which values belong to which key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't just store the values, you store them along with the keys. So when you search for a key in the linked list you traverse through the list and look for the key you want.